# One big neural network or many small neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am facing a prediction task where I have to predict the same information from the same process for a number of customers (on the order of thousands). The customers have a varying number of possible endpoints unique for every customer, which I should predict in addition.

Is it better to build a single huge prediction network or a small individual network for every customer?

My reasoning so far is that the many small nets will definitely be feasible and can be optimized for every customer individually, however I need to automatize absolutely everything because it is not possible to set up, optimize and maintain a few thousand networks by hand. On the other hand, a single huge network might not be feasible (I would have to predict from among several thousand classes), but if it works the fact that I have a lot more data will make the network aware of more subtle effects.

I am looking for criteria in favor of many small or a single large network that I missed and/or reports from somebody's experience.

Comment: you may have different networks for different kinds of customers, if they're obviously different, e.g. retail vs wholesale. building a network per customer doesn't sound reasonable, defeats the purpose